# How to test plugin development with Git Hub Actions (integration tests)?

Tags: plugins, testing

I am learning CI/CD pipeline and I had created a single one to deploy to staging environment every time I push to develop branch, using GitHub Actions.

I also understood how to perform unit tests with PHPUnit locally.

My question is, how to assure my plugin code changes will not break my staging site during the deploy? How can I test with my changes triggers an Error 500 or something related? Should I use PHPUnit or some existing GH Action?

I am a bit confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple GitHub Actions available in the [Marketplace](https://github.com/marketplace?category=&query=&type=actions&verification=) for checking response codes:

- https://github.com/marketplace/actions/check-url-status
- https://github.com/marketplace/actions/http-status

There's also this question on Stack Overflow if you want to do it custom:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65728933/how-to-capture-a-curl-http-status-code-in-a-github-action-to-determine-success-f